# how to add arrays in dictionary based on particular key

Tags: iphone

I am making an app. where i want to add vendor name and it's device name..
I am using a dictionary where vendor name is key and device name are values..

Here is my code

```
[appDelegate.arrOfDevice addObject:txtDeviceName.text];
[appDelegate.dictOfDetails setObject:appDelegate.arrOfDevice  forKey:txtVendorName.text ];
```

Here `arrOfDevice` is an array(declared in `appdelegate`) which is having all devices which are added..
I want to add devices  based on particular keys...

I know, i am doing something wrong,

I am pushing the array as values in dictionary so it will store all the device names for each key.. but please help me...So that i could store device names based on particular key...

If u are not able to understand please fell free to get clarification of my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding key for the first time then you need to do this as shown below

```
if(flag==1) {
            NSMutableArray *tmpArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [tmpArr addObject:txtDeviceName.text];
            [appDelegate.dictOfDetails setObject:tmpArr forKey:[txtVendorName.text uppercaseString]];
}
```

and if the key is present you just need to create a reference for an array and add object to the dictionary

```
      else if(flag==0) {
            NSMutableArray *arrDevice=[appDelegate.dictOfDetails objectForKey:[txtVendorName.text uppercaseString]];
            [arrDevice addObject:txtDeviceName.text] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nit",[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil]
                                              forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"num",nil]];
```

**>>Edited**

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
```

[also seem +dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: @Nit-- thanks for the answer ,but kindly tell me,if i am taking vendor name and device name from user both , then how the code will be? Here as you have posted.....Title=Screen J and View=3...but for different vendor and device..how code will be like?

Comment: It's simple that first array is your value and second one will be your key...See my edited and

Comment: @Nit--If for the first time i am adding some value for some vendor ,it will get added and when second time i am trying to add the value for the same vendor,the previous values is getting overwritten...so what to do sir?

Comment: Look at first solution with array...you can object in array and that won't be overwritten...like...... `NSMutableArray *maraay = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    [maraay addObject:@"1"];
    [maraay addObject:@"2"];
    NSLog(@"dfkl=%@",maraay);`

Comment: add value in both array( vendor array and it's key value array) and use 1st solution...enjoy..

Comment: @Nit--I know i am driving you crazy ,,but suppose i have "vendorName" as vendor name and "deviceName" as device name...so i will add as like------                                                             appdelegate.dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:deviceName.text,nil]
                                              forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vendorName.text,nil]];....this will add for first time but for next it will override...please help.....i am totally confused....

Comment: yes but your array will not overwritten and the end your array contain all vendor names...for example...in vendor name array you have entered v1,v2,v3 and that after you add this array in dictionary so dictionary will contain all the vendors name, After that you can again add vendor v1,v2,v3 that add in vendor name array. So your vendor name array have v1,v1,v3,v1,v2,v3 all vendor names right... add this array in dictionary. So your dictionary will have all vendor names ..and that's what you want..

Comment: Sorry again...My question is something other....as you can see in my first code..I have set array as my object in which i have put all device values whether it is of some other key also...this is wrong but i am not getting a way to put values in the array based on their key ie; if  someone has added new vwndor the array should contain only those device names which are put for that array....

Comment: In simple word above two methods is sufficient for your requirements...I don't know why you are not getting it..try to under stand above two method and that after use it according your needs...actually i didn't understand your last comment..